# Using reflect to detect nil value

Tags: go

I'm using the reflect package to create a re-usable JSON parser that maps JSON data to a particular struct at run-time.

I want it to detect when a particular required field is missing.

I create an variable "parsedInput" using:

```
parsedInput := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(exampleInputObject).Elem())
```

I've then used the JSON libraries to parse the data into that variable.  I now want to traverse through the values to spot anything missing:

```
    for i := 0; i < parsedInput.Elem().NumField(); i++ {
            logger.Info("Field name was: " + field.Name)
            fieldType := fmt.Sprintf("'%v'", field.Type.Kind().String())
            logger.Info("Field type was: " + fieldType)
            interfaceValue := fmt.Sprintf("'%v'", parsedInput.Elem().Field(i).Interface())
            logger.Info("Interface value was: " + interfaceValue)

            //Look to see if the field is a null pointer.  If so, this could be an issue
            if (field.Type.Kind().String() == "ptr") && (parsedInput.Elem().Field(i).Interface() == nil) {
        //Do null pointer stuff here
    }
}
```

For the field that's missing, I see the log output

```
Field name was: MissingFieldName
Field type was 'ptr'
Interface value was '<nil>'
```

My code is never dropping into the null pointer logic however - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what the values of `field` and `parsedInput` are in actuality. Also using strings as confirmation of type/kind or value is a bad idea in general, so maybe don't do that, maybe just use the `reflect.Kind` constants and `(reflect.Value).IsNil`.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment above - I managed to solve this using built-in functions in the Reflect package - specifically by testing for:

```
Reflect.ValueOf(parsedInput.Elem().Field(i).Interface()).IsNil()
```

Comment: Why not use `IsNil` directly on the `reflect.Value` returned by `Field(i)`?

Comment: You can also use `IsZero` if your "required" rule cares about the "zero-ness" of values: https://play.golang.com/p/cRCdSFBGRRe